# how to re-organized a column based on other number repetition column in a datframe in r?

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation, organization

My dataframe (1700000x3) has 3 columns:

- date: from 2011 to 2019 (throughout the dates random days and months were chosen)
- light: go from 350 to 2299 (one by one) and then restarts
- ID: the target
- V: value

This is how my data looks like (quick example) :

| date | light | ID | V |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2013-06-17 | 350 | p01 | 0.1 |
| 2013-06-17 | 351 | p01 | 0.1 |
| 2013-06-17 | 352 | p01 | 0.2 |
| 2013-06-17 | 353 | p01 | 0.3 |
| 2013-06-17 | 354 | p01 | 0.1 |
| 2013-06-17 | 355 | p01 | 0.1 |
| 2013-04-18 | ... | p01 | 0.1 |
| 2013-06-17 | 2297 | p01 | 0.2 |
| 2013-06-17 | 2298 | p01 | 0.3 |
| 2013-06-17 | 2299 | p01 | 0.2 |
| 2014-04-18 | 350 | r03 | 0.1 |
| 2014-04-18 | 351 | r03 | 0.4 |
| 2014-04-18 | 352 | r03 | 0.1 |
| 2014-04-18 | 353 | r03 | 0.6 |
| 2014-04-18 | 354 | r03 | 0.2 |
| 2014-04-18 | 355 | r03 | 0.1 |
| 2014-04-18 | ... | r03 | 0.1 |
| 2014-04-18 | 2297 | r03 | 0.5 |
| 2014-04-18 | 2298 | r03 | 0.5 |
| 2014-04-18 | 2299 | r03 | 0.6 |

All good until here! The problem was that in the middle of the data frame the LIGHT column instead of having the numbers from 350 to 2299 it had the numbers from 2299 to 350. These were verified for several IDs.
A section of the data frame looks like this:

| date | light | ID | V |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2014-07-31 | 2299 | s01 | 0.1 |
| 2014-07-31 | 2298 | s01 | 0.1 |
| 2014-07-31 | 2297 | s01 | 0.2 |
| 2014-07-31 | 2296 | s01 | 0.3 |
| 2014-07-31 | 2295 | s01 | 0.1 |
| 2014-07-31 | 2294 | s01 | 0.1 |
| 2014-07-31 | ... | s01 | 0.1 |
| 2014-07-31 | 352 | s01 | 0.2 |
| 2014-07-31 | 351 | s01 | 0.3 |
| 2014-07-31 | 350 | s01 | 0.2 |
| 2014-07-31 | 2299 | x03 | 0.1 |
| 2014-07-31 | 2298 | x03 | 0.4 |
| 2014-07-31 | 2297 | x03 | 0.1 |
| 2014-07-31 | 2296 | x03 | 0.6 |
| 2014-07-31 | 2295 | x03 | 0.2 |
| 2014-07-31 | 2294 | x03 | 0.1 |
| 2014-07-31 | ... | x03 | 0.1 |
| 2014-07-31 | 352 | x03 | 0.5 |
| 2014-07-31 | 351 | x03 | 0.5 |
| 2014-07-31 | 350 | x03 | 0.6 |

What I want is to have the LIGHT column ALWAYS with the number intervals from 350 to 2299 and then restarts from 350 to 2299 and so on. This operation has to respect the other columns, date, V "values", and the ID.

IMPORTANT NOTE: I have the same code for different dates!!

I'm having trouble finding an answer to such a specific question.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just sort it on ID then light?

```r
your.data %<>% arrange( ID, light )
```

Comment: Thanks. That does not work because it groups all IDs and correspondent values values throughout each light. For example, p01 when light is 350, r03 when light is 350, s01 when light is 350 and so on. What I want is to maintain the sequence of the light values (350 to 2299) for each ID individually. For example: ID = s01 has the light. 350, 351 352...2298, 2299, sequence .

Comment: I don't understand.. each ID has its own sequence of light values, right? Sorting first by ID, then by light seems to be the right way

Comment: That's true. The problem is that I the same code for different dates and then with this code the sequence is not respect. I forgot to write that. I'm sorry.

Comment: Well with some adjustments to the code I managed to solve it. Thank you